# printing value from variable returning the existing paths using '*' unix

Tags: shell, unix, echo

how could I print a variable that has '*', I just want to print value and is taking it as "all"

example of what I want:

```
var=/home/us*r/
echo ${var}

Result:
/home/us*r/
```

example of what is doing

```
var=/home/us*r/
echo ${var}

Result:
/home/user/
/home/usar/
/home/usir/
```

any idea of how to print just the value of variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the variable expansion in double quotes:

```
echo "$var"
```

Curly braces are optional and they help if you want to interpolate a variable expansion in a string where it's surrounded by a character that's valid in a variable name, e.g.: `echo "${var}_$var2"`, but it's double quotes that supress pathname expansion and field splitting.

See the **Word Expansion** section of [dash(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dash) for more details.